# Showing that a set is open

Tags: metric-spaces

Endow $R^2$ with the metric $d(a,b)$ ={ $max{|a_1-b_1|,|a_2-b_2|}$} where $a$=$(a_1,a_2)$ and $b$=$(b_1,b_2)$.

Show that $S$={${a \in R^2|a_1^2+a_2^2<1}$} is open in $R^2$ with this metric.

$S$ is definitely open with respect to the euclidean metric in $R^2$,but how can i show that it is open with respect to the metric given in this question?

Comment: where does the metric come into play here? The set S doesn't use it at all...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Around each point, can you construct a square, thereby proving under your metric the set is open?

Comment: $0$ will definitely be an interior point of the  set $S$,so if i construct a square around $0$ which is an arbitrary point of the set $S$ will i be done ?

Comment: @johny $(0,0)$ is **not** an arbitrary point of $S$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes you are right, it is not.My mistake.

Comment: @johny: Take an arbitrary point $(x,y)\in S$. How far away from the boundary of $S$ is the point under the Euclidean metric? Can you use that information to determine an appropriate distance so that the point is inside a square?

Answer (score 0):

For each point $x$ in $S$, the distance from $x$ to the boundary of the circle is actually $|a|-|x|$. Put it in another way. We draw a circle $C$ centered at $x$ with radius $|a|-|x|$. For each point $y$ in $C$, $|y|\le |y-x|+|x| \le |a|-|x|+|x|=|a|$. This means $y$ lies in $S$, and $C$ is contained in $S$. Therefore, $S$ is an open set.